# Small radical of $F(g,h)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, abc-conjecture

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202683/counterexample-to-proposition-of-granville-related-to-abc-conjecture).

Basically this question asks if the original @Granville proposition
always fails.

Is it true that for all $g,h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ s.t. $g,h$ are coprime
and $\deg(\mathrm{rad}(gh))>2$ exists squarefree $F \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and

$$(\deg F -2) \max(\deg g,\deg h) \ge \deg(\mathrm{rad}(F(g,h))) -1$$

where $\mathrm{rad}(f)$ is the radical of $f$, the product of the irreducible
factors.

We have strong experimental evidence for this.